# EXECUTE UPDATE MySQL Python вставляет не так string данные, как нужно

Tags: python, mysql

Писал чат-бота вк с базой MySQL. И возникла возможность через запрос UPDATE менять значения в базе данных, но вместо нужного мне формата, допустим 31-12-2021, вставляется туда текст такого вида '31-12-2021'. Как можно вставлять string данные без кавычек одинарных?

```
set_date = 'UPDATE users SET until = %r WHERE user_id = %s'
                q.execute(set_date, (until_date, message.from_id))
                db.commit()
```

Comment: Какой тип поля `until` в БД и какой объект (string или datetime?) хранится в переменной `until_date`?

Comment: тип поля until - TEXT, а объект типа string хранится в переменной until_date

Comment: Замените `%r` на `%s`.

Comment: спасибо большое за помощь, в этом и заключалась моя ошибка